# HTML: Have button resize automatically

Tags: html, css, button, textarea

I have a textarea and a button next to each other. I want the button to be the same height as the textarea next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the resize event for the textarea and update the button style accordingly. But as browsers do not fully implement this event, you would have to use something like http://jqueryui.com/resizable/ to bind to this event.

i.e:

```
$("textarea").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        // button style goes here
    }
});
```